# Help re protocol on landing at JFK?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, security, jfk, protocol

im a single traveller going to NYC for an adventure and  landing at JFK in three weeks. Im a complete novice and have no idea what to expect when I land, what do I do first? what security do I have to go through, in what order. Plus, on return from JFK to UK  is three hours enough time to clear all security and what is the protocol for returning. Im so very anxious about this and really worried and would appreciate some guidance from any regular traveller, who does this regularly.